# Find input value and associated html label text in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have the following setup:

```
<label for="<%= inpUserName.ClientID%>">Email</label>
<asp:TextBox id="inpUserName" runat="server" />
```

As you may noticed the label is not asp's label. How do I get the value of the input and the text of the label?

**Edit**
I am trying to loop through the posted form keys and get associated labels.

Comment: You mean in server side (when you do a postback)?

Comment: @Samer Abu Rabie yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `<asp:Label>` directly, just need to specify `AssociatedControlID`

```
<asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel"
       Text="Email"
       AssociatedControlID="inpUserName"
       runat="server">
<asp:TextBox id="inpUserName" runat="server" />
```

Comment: What's what I was looking for. Never used the `AssociatedControlID` and didn't knew it's that simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the label server-side:

```
<label runat="server" id="lblEmail" for="<%= inpUserName.ClientID%>">Email</label>
```

Then you can access its text in code behind like this:

```
// label text
string labelText = lblEmail.InnerText;
// input value
string inputValue = inpUserName.Text;
```

Comment: I need more dynamic way. Maybe I haven't been very clear on the question. I want to get all the posted form keys and associated labels.

Comment: what keys are you referring to here? for the labels mark them as runat=server and you can access them.

Comment: Posted form keys are input values

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
<label runat="server" id="ClientID" for="<%= inpUserName.ClientID%>">Email</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the textbox using the Id `var txt = inpUserName.Text;` for the label you can't, since its not a server side control and its not a request variable (input with value for instance) then you can't, unless you make it server side too and access in the same manner.